# How to add filter to all business unit in order in admin panel in magento 1.6.2

Tags: magento

I am not able to find sort out this problem, I want to filter in Bill to Name section in Order Grid in Admin Panel. Where I can choose the business owner and filter his all transaction. Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of modules available that do this. There are also plenty of tutorials available to show you how to do it yourself.

https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=magento+custom+order+grid